# When keyboard open/close at that time ChangeNotifierProvider call multiple time

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I am facing issue When keyboard open/close at that time ChangeNotifierProvider call multiple time so my full screen reload multiple time. In this widget I have attach video so widget is calling so many times then my instance is fail.

```
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: ColorManager.colorBackgroundGray,
  body: ChangeNotifierProvider<CreateRouteStep2ViewModel>(
      create: (BuildContext context) => modelProvider,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        printValue(label: "ChangeNotifierProvider", value: "");
        return Consumer<CreateRouteStep2ViewModel>(
            builder: (context, provider, c) {
          return SizedBox(
            height: double.infinity,
            width: double.infinity,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Stack(
                        children: [
                        
                          provider.viewType == CreateRouteStep2ViewType.map
                              ? SizedBox(
                                  height: 300,
                                  child: GoogleMapForCreateRoute(
                                      modelProvider: modelProvider),
                                )
                              : const SizedBox(),
             
                              ],
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                          flex: 1,
                          child: Container(
                            color: ColorManager.colorWhite,
                            child: SingleChildScrollView(
                              child: ListView.builder(
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                physics:
                                    const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                                itemCount: provider.listRouteName.length,
                                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                                  return CreateStepsItem(
                                    routeModel:
                                        provider.listRouteName[index],
                                    modelProvider: modelProvider,
                                    index: index,
                                    removeIndex: () {
                                      // Todo Remove index from marker pin and location array.
                                      modelProvider
                                          .removeIndexFromPinAndList(index);
                                    },
                                    edtLocationNameFocus: () {
                                      modelProvider.focusMap(index);
                                    },
                                    edtAudioFocus:
                                        (mainPosition, subPosition) {
                                      modelProvider.focusAudioComponent(
                                          index, subPosition);
                                    },
                                    edtVideoFocus:
                                        (mainPosition, subPosition) {
                                      modelProvider.focusVideoComponent(
                                          index, subPosition);
                                    },
                                  );
                                },
                                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                              ),
                            ),
                          )),
                      Visibility(
                        visible:
                            MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom == 0,
                        child: Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                left: 24.0, right: 24.0, bottom: 20.0),
                            child: CommonButton(
                              onPressed: () {},
                              lable: AppStrings.constTourSpichern,
                              isEnable: false,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
        });
      }),
);
```

Is there any widget behaviour is attach with keyboard?. If any one know that then please let me know.

Comment: Have you added set state anywhere in this class?

Comment: why you initialize `ChangeNotifierProvider<CreateRouteStep2ViewModel>` in this class?
then you call again `Consumer` . its redundant.

you should initialize  `ChangeNotifierProvider` in main class if you want to use it globally

Comment: i think every `onChange` , the build method re-run again, an then initialize th ChangeNotifierProvider`